# C++: Armadillo column matrix initialization ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, armadillo

I define an armadillo matrix and I try to initialize it via initialiser lists according to its [manual](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_initialisation).

It is fine unless I try to define a column matrix.

Why is it ambigious?

```
#include <armadillo>

int main()
{
    // ok : square matrix
    arma::mat A={{1.0,2.0},{3.0,4.5}};

    // ok: row matrix
    arma::mat B={3.5,4.0};

    // error: conversion from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to 
    // ‘arma::mat {aka arma::Mat<double>}’ is ambiguous
    arma::mat C={{3.5},{4.0}};

    // ok: column matrix
    arma::mat D=arma::mat({3.5,4.0}).t();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem with the C++11/14 standard. Because there is only one element in each inner set, the standard essentially says that `{{3.5},{4.0}}` can also be interpreted as `{3.5,4.0}`. In other words, `{3.5}` can be implicitly converted to `double(3.5)`. This leads to the ambiguity between the two constructors.

One possible solution is to use the Armadillo column vector constructor:

```
arma::mat C = arma::colvec( {3.5, 4.0} );
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it has something to do with definitions of array in C++ rather than Armadillo.
It seems you are initialising matrices by arrays. Thus your right value must be a definite array by C++ standard. Let's see the right values of your third definition:
`{{3.5},{4.0}}`
It does not mean a 1*2 column matrix with first row as 3.5 and second row as 4.0. It represents ANY matrix with two rows started by 3.5 and 4.0 respectively. You may have seen such a definition occasionally:
`double d_array[2][6] = {{3.5},{4.0}};`
Only the zeroth elements of each row in `d_array` are initialised. Since this right value can be given to any 2D array with two rows or more, it is not definite and cannot be given to a matrix initialiser.
I'm not sure if it makes sense, and if there are anything incorrect, please kindly notice me by commenting this answer below.

Comment: I disagree with you as this code totally works with square matrices. If I put numbers without extra wrapping that will define a row matrix. The armadillo related code for `operator =` can be found [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/6450efdb9b727539dabd13467db5a7a0f25c8b38/inst/include/armadillo_bits/Mat_bones.hpp#L762) or nearby.

Comment: @mtall, does any other solution exist or `arma::mat({3.5,4.0}).t(); is the only way?

Comment: @mtall, it worked. thanks. could you please leave it as an answer so I can close the question?

Comment: @mtall Thank you for your correction! It always feels good to learn what's right.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: the rule of the standard specification.

First, your statement

```
arma::mat C={{3.5},{4.0}};
```

*copy-initialize* an object `C`.(copy-initialization does not necessarily call a copy-constructor)
The initializer is *initializer-list*, and *list-initialization* is employed.
Because object `C` is class, *initializer-list* *construtor* is searched first.

`armadillo::Mat<eT>` has two *initializer-list* *constructor*:

```
// defined in "<include-dir>/armadillo_bits/Mat_bones.hpp"
Mat(const std::initializer_list<eT>& list);
Mat(const std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list<eT> >& list);
```

These are *candidate function*s in overload resolution.
To determine the best viable function, the partial order of implicit conversion from *initializer-list* to each parameters are considered. In this case, *list-initialization* *sequence* is used. `{3.5}`, and `{4.0}` can be converted both to `eT` and `std::initializer_list<eT>`. Important point here is that there is  implicit conversions for both case. The specification defines this kind of conversion has the worst order, and these two constructors are worst, in other words, same order which results in ambiguous overload resolution.